# How to print tcpdump format like this

Tags: tcpdump

I want to print tcpdump in the following format:

```
202    2018-06-25 18:53:54.051971    192.168.1.121    8.8.8.8    DNS    82    Standard query 0x3cba A weixin.spreadwin.com
```

I tried:

```
tcpdump -n -tttt -r ip_ok-name_failed_before.pcap
```

Which gives me the output:

```
2018-06-25 18:53:54.051971 IP 192.168.1.121.21497 > 8.8.8.8.53: 15546+ A? weixin.spreadwin.com. (38)
```

How do I achieve the expected output?

Comment: What is the 202 supposed to be?